# Woocommerce product admin sort by stock

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there anyway I can sort by stock? Since it reads 'Stock x 30' it would be helpful if I could sort by high or low. Is there any code I can add to the functions.php to enable that feature?

Answer (score 0):

easy enough... it can be accomplished with this code...

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'rei_product_sortable_columns' );
function rei_product_sortable_columns( $columns ) {
    $custom = array(
        'is_in_stock' => 'is_in_stock'
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
```

but this would just sort what the stock column has... example, 'in stock' or 'out of stock'

---

To have a custom sort, (for example, using the stock number), you may follow the instruction on this [blog post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types).

Comment: Hmm thank you. I checked that blog post and tried to add the duration code by changing the 'movies' post type to 'product' and the orderby/meta_key to stock, but it didn't work. I'm guessing these is another step perhaps? I'm just not sure how to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Working version as of: Year 2022, WP 5.9.3, WC 6.4.1:

```
// make quantity column sortable
function rei_product_sortable_columns( $columns )
{
    $custom = array(
        'is_in_stock' => 'stock_disponible'
    );
    return wp_parse_args( $custom, $columns );
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_sortable_columns', 'rei_product_sortable_columns' );

// only load on edit.php page
function my_edit_movie_load() {
    add_filter( 'request', 'my_sort_movies' );
}
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_edit_movie_load' );

// do the sorting
function my_sort_movies( $vars )
{
    /* Check if we're viewing the 'product' post type. */
    if ( isset( $vars['post_type'] ) && 'product' == $vars['post_type'] )
    {
        /* Check if 'orderby' is set to 'stock_disponible'. */
        if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'stock_disponible' == $vars['orderby'] )
        {
            /* Merge the query vars with our custom variables. */
            $vars = array_merge(
                $vars,
                array(
                    'meta_key' => '_stock',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return $vars;
}
```